# What does the star symbol mean in a triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What do the stars mean in a triangular matrix?

For example,

$\begin{bmatrix}
&A_i &B_{ij}\\
&\star &A_j
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Had the author explicitly stated that this is a triangular matrix? The star is probably a wildcard character. It denotes an unspecified element whose value is irrelevant to discussion.

Comment: If you know that it is upper (block) triangular matrix, it is for a block of zeroes.